# How to make all edges in the scene rendered by freestyle?

Tags: freestyle

Is there a way to mark all edges to be rendered with freestyle, without marking all edges as freestyle lines in each individual object one by one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple python script can turn them all on/off

```
import bpy

for object in bpy.data.objects:
    if object.type == 'MESH':
        for edge in object.data.edges:
            edge.use_freestyle_mark = True

        #show the marked edges
        object.data.show_freestyle_edge_marks = True
```

Just paste this into the text editor, and press the hotkey <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, or the <kbd>Run Script</kbd> button to run it.

Then, to remove the marks, just change `True`'s to `False`, and run the script and they should all be gone.

Comment: script above not working http://i.stack.imgur.com/WfQqr.png